# How to open a spreadsheet in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I make that, when pressing the command button, it opens the first spreadsheet of Excel?

I am coding in Visual Basic Forms in Excel 2016. This is my code:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then MsgBox (" Has decidido Actualizar el Inventario")

Workbook("Hoja1").ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: Very confusing, your title reads "Spreadsheet" your code reads "Workbook". Your description reads "Command Button", your Code reads "OptionButton"

Comment: Sorry about that, Yes im working in Option Button. The last line i believe is terrible wrong. I am coding in spanish so there might be a translation problem

Comment: and by the way thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code can be simplified into this:

```
Sub firstSheet()

Sheets(1).Select

End Sub
```

Then go to the Developer tab, add a button, and assign it to this macro.